# Sass Emmet Bug (latest patch )

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, emmet

When i use emmet in sass it adds the semicolon at the end of line, syntax is always Sass, emmet could recognize sass syntax before, now it thinks i use pure css  (Latest patch problem)
[Sass Emmet Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CHZw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, but is not a bug

Not sure if this is a new property but I checked the documentation and seen this

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet
CSS snippet values | Can end with ; | Do not add ; at end of snippet value. Emmet will add the trailing ; based on the file type (css/less/scss vs sass/stylus) or the emmet preference set for **css.propertyEnd, sass.propertyEnd, stylus.propertyEnd**

Only need open the settings.json of VS Code and add these lines

```
"emmet.preferences": {
  "sass.propertyEnd": ""
}
```